# Confusion about crawler settigs, spider settings, project settings

Tags: python, scrapy

I have confusion about crawler settings, spider settings, settings.py and project setting.I see the docunmention about scrapy while I haven't understand the difference.For example, in the function

```
process = CrawlerProcess(settings={
    "FEEDS": {
        "items.json": {"format": "json"},
    },
})
```

what does the difference, and how to use them.
Sorry for my bad english.

I want to know the difference among them.and if you have the example and can demonstrate, please attach them below.and at last,thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `FEEDS` setting is the output settings for your spider.

If you were to run

```
scrapy crawl spidername -o file.json
```

That would be roughly the same as

```
process = CrawlerProcess(settings={"FEEDS": {"file.json": {"format": "json"}})
```

Another example would be

```
scrapy crawl spidername -o file2.csv
```

is roughly the same as

```
process = CrawlerProcess(settings={"FEEDS": {"file2.csv": {"format": "csv"}})
```

So the value of the "FEEDS" setting is a dictionary, the key is the output location, and the value is the format/handler used to process each of the items generated by your spider.